# Faster way to create EventBridge Event Rules for taking EBS snapshots

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-event-bridge

I have 70 EBS volumes that I need to schedule daily snapshots of. I found [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/TakeScheduledSnapshot.html) in the AWS documentation which is helpful, and I already toyed with the AWS CLI to fetch a list of the 70 volume IDs, however, it's not clear to me how I can then feed these many volume IDs back into the Event Rule.

Through the Console, I can only add one Target (Create Snapshot API, Volume ID, and Role) at a time. Looking at the [AWS CLI documentation for put-targets](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/events/put-targets.html), I'm not seeing how to form the command to do this, even if I used some creative find-and-replace work in Notepad to just make a ton of individual commands. Namely, I'm not seeing how I select the Create Snapshot API as the Target, and since each Target has slightly different requirements, I'm not sure then how to supply the volume ID or IAM Role.

What is the most expedient way to get 70 EBS volume IDs added as Create Snapshot API Targets for an EventBridge Rule, or do I just gotta bear down and do them all by hand?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of building such a custom solution, AWS backup is nowadays a much more effective solution for these types of tasks.  It also allows you to set a retention period more easily to life cycle your snapshots and create backup policies based on tags.

If you really want to do it with cloudwatch events you need at least as many event rules as you have volumes since the snapshot api is only called once per scheduled rule and the api does not take a list of volumes, just a single volume. So you'll need 70 scheduled rules. Which doesn't scale very well :). Second option is to use a lambda for the event rule target that processes everything but again, it's more work than aws backup.

Comment: I'll definitely look at AWS Backup, thanks. Separately, a colleague suggested that I look at ways to programmatically invoke the same process that "Create Image" in the EC2 console uses, since that automatically puts together a batch job of snapshotting all the volumes, but I'm not sure how to automate that.

Comment: Aws backup also supports creating ami's if i remember correctly. So it would suit both use cases